# Material UI v5 - Property 'spacing' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme' when using a custom theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using material ui version 5, i have a custom theme which i have wrapped in all my components around.

In one of my components i am trying to give paper some padding based on my theme, however i get the following error.

> Property 'spacing' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'

```
       <AppProvider>
            <Theme>
                <Layout>
                    <ProtectedRoute>
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </ProtectedRoute>
                </Layout>
            </Theme>
        </AppProvider>
```

**campaign.tsx**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
}));

export default function Campaign(props: ICampaginProps): ReactElement | null {
    const classes = useStyles();
```

**theme.tsx**

```
const DEFAULT_THEME = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    palette: {
        mode: "light",
        primary: {
            main: "#212121",
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#fafafa",
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried this suggestion from the [MUI migration documentation](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#types-property-quot-palette-quot-quot-spacing-quot-does-not-exist-on-type-defaulttheme):

> **[Types] Property "palette", "spacing" does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'**
>
> Since `makeStyles` is now exported from `@mui/styles` package which does
> not know about `Theme` in the core package. To fix this, you need to
> augment the `DefaultTheme` (empty object) in `@mui/styles` with `Theme` from
> the core.
>
> **TypeScript Project**
>
> Put this snippet to your theme file:

```
// it could be your App.tsx file or theme file that is included in your tsconfig.json
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/styles/defaultTheme' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface (remove this line if you don't have the rule enabled)
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

> **Javascript Project**
>
> If your IDE (ex. VSCode) is able to infer types from `d.ts` file,
> create `index.d.ts` in your src folder with this snippet:

```
// index.d.ts
declare module "@mui/private-theming" {
  import type { Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";

  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution I found is to type `theme` and import `styled` from mui. I'm using an alias to `styled` in the case anyone uses emotion or styled components and wants to use that CSS.

```
    import { Theme, styled as styledMui } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Paper } from '@mui/material'

    export const CustomPaper = styledMui(Paper)(({ theme }: { theme: Theme }) => `
  padding: ${theme.spacing(3)};
`);;
```

Or following the object alternative:

```
export const CustomPaper = styledMui(Paper)(({ theme }: { theme: Theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(3),
}));
```